# how to cache webp images in service worker?

Tags: gulp, service-worker, bundling-and-minification, webp, gulp-imagemin

I am doing image minification and conversion to webp using gulp through the following code:

```
gulp.task('minify-images', function(){
  return gulp.src('img/*.+(png|jpg|gif)')
  .pipe(imagemin([
        imagemin.jpegtran({progressive: true}),
        imagemin.gifsicle({interlaced: true}),
        imagemin.optipng({optimizationLevel: 5})
        ]))
  .pipe(webp())
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img'))
});
```

I am getting following error in console:
[image: console error]

Do I need to make any changes to my service worker since the console error is pointing towards service worker??

```
 self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
   console.log("Service Worker installed");
event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll([
        './',
        './index.html',
        './rt.html',
        './offline.html',   
        './manifest.json',
        // Remove rts.json from cache as  data is  coming from server.
        './css/styles.css',
        './img/1.jpg',
        './img/2.jpg',
        './img/3.jpg',
        './img/4.jpg',
        './img/5.jpg',
        './img/6.jpg',
        './img/7.jpg',
        './img/8.jpg',
        './img/9.jpg',
        './img/10.jpg',
        './img/marker-icon-2x-red.png',
        './img/marker-shadow.png',
        './img/offlinegiphy.gif',
        './img/icons/iconman.png',
        './img/icons/iconman-48x48.png',
        './img/icons/iconman-64x64.png',
        './img/icons/iconman-128x128.png',
        './img/icons/iconman-256x256.png',
        './img/icons/iconman-512x512.png',
        './js/dbhelper.js',
        './js/main.js',
        './js/rt_info.js',
        './register_sw.js',
        './serviceworker.js',
        'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css',
        'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js',
         ]);
    })
  );
   console.log("cache successful");
});
```

I tried changing the extension to webp for jpg images but that also not worked.
I have a few queries :

- why I am getting the error for only jpg images is it because these images are fetching from the API?
- how to handle all image formats caching in service worker after gulp minification and conversions?

Please Help in sorting this out I am so confused here if you can point me to some good resources as well it will be great help !!

***Edit 1:***

***Updated serviceworker.js code***
`

```
const staticCacheName = 'rt-rws-v4';
var imgCache = 'rt-img';

var filesToCache=[
        './',
        './index.html',
        './rt.html',
        './offline.html',   
        './manifest.json',
        // Remove rt.json from cache as  data is  coming from server.
        './css/styles.css',
        './js/dbhelper.js',
        './js/main.js',
        './js/rt_info.js',
        './js/idb.js',
        'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.css',
        'https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.3.1/dist/leaflet.js',
         ];
/**
 * This block is invoked when install event is fired
 */
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.addAll(filesToCache);
    })
  );
});
// deletes old cache
self.addEventListener('activate', function(event) {
  // console.log("Service Worker activated");
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.keys().then(function(cacheNames) {
      return Promise.all(
        cacheNames.filter(function(cacheName) {
          return cacheName.startsWith('rt-rws-') &&
                 cacheName != staticCacheName;
        }).map(function(cacheName) {
          return caches.delete(cacheName);
        })
      );
       console.log("Old cache removed");
    })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
    var requestUrl = new URL(event.request.url);
    // Check if the image type
  if (/\.(jpg|png|gif|webp).*$/.test(requestUrl.pathname)) {
      event.respondWith(cacheImages(event.request));
   return;
}
event.respondWith(
  /*  fetch(returnUrl, {
             mode: 'no-cors'
           }) */
    caches.open(staticCacheName).then(function(cache) {
      return cache.match(event.request).then(function (response) {
        if (response) {
          // console.log("data fetched from cache");
          return response;
        }
        else {
          return fetch(event.request).then(function(networkResponse) {
            // console.log("data fetched from network", event.request.url);
            //cache.put(event.request, networkResponse.clone());
            return networkResponse;
          }).catch(function(error) {
            console.log("Unable to fetch data from network", event.request.url, error);
          });
        }
      });
    }).catch(function(error) {
     // console.log("Something went wrong with Service Worker fetch intercept", error);
     return caches.match('offline.html', error);

    })
  );
});

/**
* @description Adds images to the imgCache
* @param {string} request
* @returns {Response}
*/
function cacheImages(request) {
  var storageUrl = new URL(request.url).pathname;

  return caches.open(imgCache).then(function(cache) {
    return cache.match(storageUrl).then(function(response) {
      if (response) return response;

      return fetch(request).then(function(networkResponse) {
        cache.put(storageUrl, networkResponse.clone());
        return networkResponse;
      });
    });
  });
}

/* // Inspect the accept header for WebP support
  var supportsWebp = false;
  if (event.request.headers.has('accept')){
    supportsWebp = event.request.headers
                                .get('accept')
                                    .includes('webp');
        }
        // If we support WebP
    if (supportsWebp)
    {
        // Clone the request
        var req = event.request.clone();

            // Build the return URL
            var returnUrl = req.url.substr(0, req.url.lastIndexOf(".")) + ".webp";
    //console.log("Service Worker starting fetch"); */
```

`
No issues with gulp task successfully run and  doing task

> [09:10:50] Using gulpfile gulpfile.js
>
> [09:10:50] Starting 'minify-images'...
>
> [09:10:51] gulp-imagemin: Minified 18 image (saved 12.84 kB - 6.6%)
>
> [09:10:51] Finished 'minify-images' after 108 ms

chrome  headers

> Request URL: http://localhost:8000/img/6
>
> Request Method: GET Status Code: 404 Not Found (from ServiceWorker)
>
> Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:8000
>
> Referrer Policy:no-referrer-when-downgrade
>
> Connection: keep-alive
>
> Content-Length: 0
>
> Date: Fri, 16 Nov 2018 13:43:03 GMT
>
> server: ecstatic-3.2.2 Provisional headers are shown
>
> Referer: http://localhost:8000/
>
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Nexus 5 Build/MRA58N)
>
> AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.102 Mobile Safari/537.36

Comment: you have .jpg and .webp files existent in `/img` directory? what exactly is pointing towards service worker in the console error? and i would say it's better to not cache `./register_sw.js` and `./serviceworker.js` with the service-worker itself, else you can't update

Comment: @AndréKelling there is no issue with image optimization and conversion to webp all images are optimized and converted to webp and stored in dist folder...I updated my service worker code not caching service worker files anymore..for now removing manually catching each images I am working on updating  service worker code for caching images in the service  via function i think that will work if issue still persist  i will update the question here

Comment: @AndréKelling  Updated service worker code but the issue still persist gulp minify-images task is running successfully so  I  guess the issue is with service worker only added headers information still not able to understand the cause ...Please help

Comment: you said they are stored in `dist` folder: do you mean the `img` folder? can you check whats in the cache? in chrome dev tools `Application` > `Cache Storage` > `Name of your cache`

Comment: @AndréKelling thanks for your help I figured out !! It's working now.

Answer (score 1):

Your compressed webp files are stored in `dist/img` but should get saved in `img` directory.

Because they are requested from `img`.